# Excel field to Excel field comparison using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a requirement where i need to compare excel to excel and create a third excel with True(where column value matches) and False(in case the match fails) using Python.

Can someone please assist with the piece of code with explanation.

Much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please make sure to take a tour.

Comment: and the link to the tour page can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

If you could please specify what tools you plan on using that would be great. We can accomplish the task in python using the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library.

Assuming that you are using python 3 with openpyxl, and your files are located in directory "C:\Users\Me\files" and are called "file1.xlsx" and "file2.xlsx":

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

path = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\files'

# open xcel sheets
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(path + 'file1.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(path + 'file2.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.active

# create new workbook
wb3 = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws3 = wb3.active
wb3.save(path + 'file3.xlsx')

# compare each element
for row in range(ws1.max_row):
    for column in range(ws1.max_column):
        column_letter = get_column_letter(column)
        cell = column_letter + str(row)

        if ws1[cell].value == ws2[cell].value:
            ws3[cell].value = 'True'
        else:
            ws3[cell].value = 'False'

wb3.save(path + 'file3.xlsx')
```